# What model should a SQLalchemy database column be to contain an array of data?

Tags: python, attributes, sqlalchemy, flask

So I am trying to set up a database, the rows of which will be modified frequently. Every hour, for instance, I want to add a number to a particular part of my database. So if `self.checkmarks` is entered into the database equal to `3`, what is the best way to update this part of the database with an added number to make `self.checkmarks` now equal `3, 2`? I tried establishing the column as `db.Array` but got an attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Array'

I have found how to update a database, but I do not know the best way to update by adding to a list rather than replacing. My approach was as follows, but I don't think `append` will work because the column cannot be an array:

```
ven = data.query.filter_by(venid=ven['id']).first()
ven.totalcheckins = ven.totalcheckins.append(ven['stats']['checkinsCount'])
db.session.commit()
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you familiar with [relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html) on SQLAlchemy (or in relational databases in general)?

Comment: I read a bit about them in the docs but not really. Is this worth exploring to try and achieve this effect?

Comment: Yes. A one-to-many relationship is exactly what you want in this case. SQLAlchemy's documentation is **excelent** and I recommend you read that first. You'll see that the first case explained in the link I posted in my first comment is precisely what you want: you'll need an additional table for your `checkmarks` which will have a foreign key relationship to your parent table. When you define a relationship involving both tables, SQLAlchemy will map this automatically to a collection.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Perfect! I will read up on that. Many thanks

Comment: if you do actually want to use "Array", it's available in the Postgresql dialect as sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY.

Comment: Thank you. I will certainly explore and read up on that.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to have a python list as a Column in SQLAlchemy you will want to have a look at the [PickleType](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType):

```
array = db.Column(db.PickleType(mutable=True))
```

Please note that you will have to use the `mutable=True` parameter to be able to edit the column. SQLAlchemy will detect changes automatically and they will be saved as soon as you commit them.

If you want the pickle to be human-readable you can combine it with json or other converters that suffice your purposes.

Comment: With PostgreSQL, you can use the [ARRAY](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY) column type

Comment: Please see also the [ScalarListType provided by SQLAlchemy-utils](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.scalar_list). It's pretty handy!